# How can I prevent updated Parse objects from moving to the front of my array?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

**For Context:**

I have a UITableView which displays UITableViewCells of drawings completed by users. This tableview pulls data stored on my Parse account and is attempting to display the cells in reverse chronological order, the most recently submitted drawing at the top.

I have a "like" button on each cell which adds the current users name to an array on each drawing object. If the current users name is present in that array, then the like button is already colored in, indicating that they have already liked the drawing.

However, when a user "likes" a drawing, their name is added to the array using `.addUniqueObject` which "updates" the drawing object on Parse, and is somehow moving it to the front of the array. Thus showing the old drawing at the top of the feed just because someone has liked it.

How can I avoid this? I want to ignore the fact that adding the current users name to the `whoLiked` array on my parse object makes the app think its the most recent drawing.

*I want the items to stay in place in the array and order the drawings in the Table View based on the time/date they were submitted **only**.*

**My Code:**

In **HomeFeedTableViewController** I call `loadData()` in several places. Here is `loadData()`:

```
func loadData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()
    var findHomeFeedData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserDrawing")

    findHomeFeedData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects!{
                let drawinn:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(drawinn)
            }

            // this reverseObjectEnumerator thing just displays in chronological order (reversed order)
            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
```

`timelineData` is `var timelineData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`

Each custom **UITableViewCell** (DrawingTableViewCell) has a `heartButtonPressed` IBAction:

```
@IBAction func heartButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    let timelineData = dataSource?.getTimelineData(self)
    let indexPath = dataSource?.getIndexPath(self)

    println("timelineData is: \(timelineData)")
    println("indexPath is: \(indexPath)")

    let drawinn: PFObject = timelineData!.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! PFObject
    println("objectID is: \(drawinn.objectId)")

    PFUser.currentUser()?.addUniqueObject(drawinn.objectId!, forKey: "liked")
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    drawinn.addUniqueObject(user!, forKey: "whoLiked")
    drawinn.saveInBackground()

    if(parseObject != nil) {
        if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes!++

            parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
            parseObject!.saveInBackground()

            likesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)"
            self.heartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart_button_filled"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }

    heartImageView?.hidden = false
    heartImageView?.alpha = 1.0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.0, options:nil, animations: {

        self.heartImageView?.alpha = 0

        }, completion: {
            (value:Bool) in

            self.heartImageView?.hidden = true
    })
}
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if you need further clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw that Parse supplies `addAscendingOrder` and `addDescendingOrder` to `PFQuery`s. So to solve my problem, I added the following line to my `loadData()` method:

`findHomeFeedData.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")`